# Exotic smooth structures on HK manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

An HK manifold is a closed simply-connected Kähler manifold $M$ such that $H^0(M, \Omega_M^2)=\mathbb{C}\omega$, where $\omega$ is a holomorphic 2-form on $M$ which is nowhere degenerate  as a skew-symmetric form on the tangent space.

If two HK manifolds are homeomorphic are they diffeomorphic?